# OpenVPN dns on windows: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

I recently set up a openVPN server (pivpn). The VPN is working really well. I can connect to my home internal network through the VPN. For custom domains I used my router (fritz box) as a DNS server:

```
push "route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0"

push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.178.1"
```

Problem:  My Windows pc cannot resolve my domains (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED). It works on my android phone and also on my WSL - Ubuntu subsystem (Strangely). I found some solutions on the internet: But the network interface metric change doesn't do the trick (VPN interface already at 1). Moreover, the nslookup also resolves the hostname successfully. Chrome, Opera, Edge, internet explorer are not working.

Please share some thoughts.

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions that I found for windows is to use the OpenVPN GUI - https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/ app as it seems to work and route the networks correctly.

I have also tried all of the solutions that you have probably found on the first 1-10 pages of the search results.

Let me know if you found a workaround with the OpenVPN Connect app so that we can help other people as well.

Note: I am using Pritunl as the VPN Server.